# "Видно, ночами репетировали – на прошлом представлении они прикололись – поменялись голосами!" - что делать с тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> А знаете, они <дельфины> тут такой трюк придумали! Знаете, как они
>   тренера недавно разыграли? **Видно, ночами репетировали – на прошлом
>   представлении они прикололись – поменялись голосами!** Белуха открывала
>   рот во время пения, а подавала голос афалина! Тренер чуть в воду от
>   удивления не свалился, а эти хихикали там по-своему, понимаете?

Может, так:

*Видно, ночами репетировали... На прошлом представлении они прикололись – поменялись голосами!*

Comment: А если так: *Видно, ночами репетировали... На прошлом представлении они прикололись – поменялись голосами: белуха открывала рот во время пения, а подавала голос афалина!*

Comment: Так у меня ж это в вопросе - нижняя строка. Тут же требуют: а где ваш вариант правки? Вот он он. Ой! Нужно поправить шапку вопроса, а тогда Вы можете не поверить, что я не вносила правку в текст. Если ж речь о двоеточии после "голосами", то у рассказчика рубленые фразы, всё на восклицаниях.

Comment: Если не подходит двоеточие, то тогда я за Ваш вариант. *Видно, ночами репетировали... На прошлом представлении они прикололись – поменялись голосами!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видно, ночами репетировали и на прошлом представлении  прикололись – поменялись голосами!

Comment: А почему бы и нет? Как говорится, просто о со вкусом.